# Confused with different behaviors of nodes and literal points when using origin option

Tags: pstricks

I have not found a document explaining my problem below. In my understanding, if `\pnode(1,1){A}` then `\pscircle[origin={A}](A){1}` must be identical to

- `\pscircle[origin={1,1}](A){1}`
- `\pscircle[origin={A}](1,1){1}`
- `\pscircle[origin={1,1}](1,1){1}`

However, I got the following result that is different from my mental model above. How does PSTricks make assumption when handling nodes and literal points?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\psset{linecolor=red}

\def\xxx{\hspace{5mm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](3,3)
\pnode(1,1){A}
\pscircle[origin={A}](A){1}
\end{pspicture}\xxx

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](3,3)
\pnode(1,1){A}
\pscircle[origin={1,1}](A){1}
\end{pspicture}\xxx

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](3,3)
\pnode(1,1){A}
\pscircle[origin={A}](1,1){1}
\end{pspicture}\xxx

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](3,3)
\pscircle[origin={1,1}](1,1){1}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would the explanation on page 23 of the [`pstricks` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/pstricks-doc.pdf) be a credible source for the answer?

Comment: @percusse: No information on page 23 about the relationship between nodes, `origin` and literal points.

Comment: Document page number 23, literal page number 30.

Comment: @percusse: please quote them in your answer. I have not found the relevant statements on the given page number.

Comment: @StiffJokes Why a new bounty?

Comment: @PaulGaborit: Just for fun.

Comment: @StiffJokes What do you hope for? A new answer? Some details? Nothing?

Comment: @PaulGaborit: I need reliable, self-contained, yet compact explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`origin={x,y}` is the equivalent of `shift={(x,y)}` supplied to a scope in TikZ or a local shift to the coordinate system:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (o) {O};
\begin{scope}[shift={(2,2)}]
\node (a) at (o) {A};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

In this one it doesn't matter if the coordinate system is shifted or not. The command says put this at node named `(o)`. So no shift is applied. Same happens with the `origin={A}`. The code says shift the coordinate system but then the same code says put it where `A` is so the net effect is moving the center of the circle to `{A}`.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\psset{linecolor=red}


\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](5,3)
\pnode(2,1){A}
\pscircle[origin={1,1}](A){1} %<---- A is a fixed point, no effect via origin 
\psdiamond[framearc=.3,fillstyle=solid,      %<---- No fixed point, coords of A are 
fillcolor=lightgray,origin={A}](3,0)(1.5,1)  % added to the coordinate system
\pscircle[origin={1,1}](0,0){1}              % Same here
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want to offer a bounty for my another question. But this one must be finalized first.  Actually I don't understand well your answer.